# Does an exponential series converge uniformly all the time?

Tags: real-analysis

As the title already mentioned. If not, could you please give me a counterexample?

Comment: Suppose we have $e^z$, its radius of convergence must be $\rho = \infty$. A power series centered at 0 converges uniformly in any ball $B(0,r)$ with $r \in (0, \rho)$. So, it converges uniformly in any ball with $r>0$. It's just what I think, please do correct me if I'm wrong